# jquery sortable not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I can use jquery to sort an individual list and sort between lists.  However when I attempt to do both, the individual sort works really poorly.  (Seemingly can only find room at the end)  It seems has to do with specifying the width of the li.  Any ideas.
Thanks all - ive been struggling for too long.
Website its located at is :
http://s95311055.onlinehome.us/midwives2012/sortFields-test.php

jquery

```
$(function() {
 $( "#category1, #category2" ).sortable({items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)",connectWith: "#removed"}).disableSelection();
```

});

CSS

```
._32 {
 width: 28%;
display: inline;
float: left;
padding-left: 2%;
padding-right: 2%;
padding-bottom: 2%;
margin:5px;
background-color: #FFC;
```

}

```
          <ul class="category" id="category1"><span class="categoryHeader">List1<br></span>
  <li class="_32">num1</li>    
  <li class="_32">num2</li>    
  <li class="_32">num3</li>    
  <li class="_32">num4</li>    
  <li class="_32">num5</li>    
  <li class="_32">num6</li>                                  
  <li class="_32">num7</li>    
  <li class="_32">num8</li>    
  <li class="_32">num9</li>    
  <li class="_32">num10</li>    
  <li class="_32">num11</li>    
  <li class="_32">num12</li>        
</ul>
<ul class="category" id="category2"><span class="categoryHeader">List2<br></span>
  <li class="_32">num21</li>    
  <li class="_32">num22</li>    
  <li class="_32">num23</li>    
  <li class="_32">num24</li>    
  <li class="_32">num25</li>    
  <li class="_32">num26</li>                                  
  <li class="_32">num27</li>    
  <li class="_32">num28</li>    
  <li class="_32">num29</li>    
  <li class="_32">num30</li>    
  <li class="_32">num31</li>    
  <li class="_32">num32</li>        

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a known issue in jquery sortable.
Here is the [bug report](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8792)

Comment: thanks so much for the info-  i couldnt find that and was just bashing my head against the wall.